# Find every weekend in a week: \advdate, \datetime

Tags: tikz-pgf, datetime, advdate

I am creating my own calendar. That means for each page in my book a day is reserved: **dd.mm.yyy (day of week)**.

Via a foreach loop I change the current date:

```
\usepackage{advdate}
\usepackage{datetime} 



\foreach \days in {1, 3, 5, ..., 365} 
{
\AdvanceDate[\days]
...
     \AdvanceDate[\days].
     \DrawDateLeftSite{\today}
    \DrawDateRightSite{\AdvanceDate[1]\today}
.....
}
```

I now want to find out if a date is a weekend. If this is the case, I want to write the weekend on a page: **dd.mm.yyy / dd.mm.yyy (Saturday / Sunday)**

```
\usepackage{advdate}
\usepackage{datetime} 


\foreach \days in {1, 3, 5, ..., 365} 
{
...
     \AdvanceDate[\days].

    % if(weekend)
    % DrawWeekend{\today, \AdvanceDate[1]\today}

     \DrawDateLeftSite{\today}
    \DrawDateRightSite{\AdvanceDate[1]\today}
.....
}
```

I hope you can help me and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about `datetime` but this test is certainly doable with `pgfcalendar` without `advdate`, for this you just add `\days` to the current date `\year-\month-\day` and test that date for `weekend`.

As a side effect, the weekday of that day is available in `\pgfcalendarifdateweekday`.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor, pgfcalendar}
\begin{document}
\foreach \days in {1, 3, 5, ..., 365}{%
  \days\ days after \today\ is%
  \pgfcalendarifdate
    {\year-\month-\day+\days}
    {weekend}
    {}
    { \textbf{not}}
  a weekend because it's a
  \pgfcalendarweekdayname{\pgfcalendarifdateweekday}.
  \par}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Just like what I've seen in other places, you put a ```%``` at the end of a line. Why do so?

Comment: @youthdoo To suppress a space from appearing in my text. The end of a line will be converted into a space (unless it won't). See for example [Q7453](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453) or its related questions. You can check for yourself by removing or adding them at the end of the line and see how the output changes.